# Merging tesselated terrain with manually modelled

Tags: terrain, heightmap, tessellation

In my flighsim visual system I am rendering large scale terrain using fixed grid mesh which is tesselated and displaced using height map. But for some relative small area (usually airports) we have much more detailed models including terrain, runways and so on. And here is a problem how can I merge tesselated terrain with modelled one?

On the picture bellow grey is a tesselated terrain, and blue is modelled with 3dsmax.

[image]